# DQS - matching empty domains

Tags: sql-server-2012, matching, data-quality-services

Is it a way to configure matching rules in the DQS **Data Quality Project** to ignore matching the empty domains?
I find it very strange if two empty domain values are considered as match for 100%. I always can, of course, write the `newid()` in all the empty domains inside the underlying sql data source (view), but this is overkill and maybe there are "right" way to do this...

[image: Matching Score Details]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found acceptable solution.
Empty fields inside *composite domain* are not considered as matched.

By the way if *all* the composite domain fields of two records are blank, then these domains are considered as matched on 100%. But I am quite satisfied this that.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this feature is not currently supported so only the workarounds you list above exist.

"Null values in the corresponding fields of two records will be considered a match"

sources:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213071.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7b52419c-0bb8-4e56-b920-e68ff551bd76/can-i-set-a-matching-rule-to-only-match-if-the-value-is-not-null?forum=sqldataqualityservices

A note when implementing any workaround - the performance will be negatively impacted. You will notice this more with larger data sets.

FWIW The workaround I implemented:

- save matching results to a table, include a column isMatchingScoreAdjusted default 0
- find all records that have a null match and calculate adjusted value
- update results

example proc

```
DECLARE @GIVEN_NAME FLOAT = 22;

WITH adjustedscore
AS (
    SELECT c.MatchingScore
        + case when  p.GIVEN_NAME is null and c.GIVEN_NAME is null then -@GIVEN_NAME else 0 end 
        as [AdjustedMatchingScore]
        ,c.RecordId
FROM [dbo].[dqs_matches] p
INNER JOIN [dbo].[dqs_matches] c ON c.SiblingId = p.RecordId
WHERE c.IsPivot = 0
    AND p.GIVEN_NAME IS NULL
    AND c.GIVEN_NAME IS NULL
)
UPDATE m SET MatchingScore = a.AdjustedMatchingScore, isMatchingScoreAdjusted = 1
FROM adjustedscore a
INNER JOIN [dbo].[dqs_matches] m ON m.RecordId = a.RecordId
where m.isMatchingScoreAdjusted = 0
```